# How to have iframe fill width and height of remaining screen area, using Bootstrap ( I guess)?

Tags: html, css, iframe, styles, size

I have some markup, then an iframe. I just want the iframe to fill whatever max width and height is currently not taken up by the rest of the markup, if that makes sense.

Code:

```
<h1>Hi!</h1>

<br />
<input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<iframe id="myI" src="mypage.html"></iframe>
```

So in this case, the iframe should take up the full width of the screen, and the height should be from the top of the frame to the bottom of the screen. What style will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your CSS. The iframe width is set using the regular type of 100% width but the height is set as 100% of the viewport.

```
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: that gives me a vertical scroll bar about the height of the markup above the frame

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by simplest way: set height less than 100%, e.g.

```
<iframe style="width: 100%;height: 95%;position: absolute" name="result"></iframe>
```

More precisely it could be done by js, I suppose.